# ¿Cómo se puede añadir un if dentro de un else - PHP?

Tags: php

Con el siguiente `if` oculto dato si existe o no desde alguna `session`

```
if(!$ticket) {
  //No existe sesión

} else {
  //Existe sesión
}
```

Ahora desde un dato verdadero necesito poder añadir dos `if` con datos verdaderos **(según el dato recibido)** desde su **raíz** `if(!$ticket)` de la siguiente manera:

```
if(!$ticket) {
  //No existe sesión

} else {
  if($operation==="extra"){
    echo "tiene hora extra";
  }
  if($operation==="noextra"){
    echo "no tiene hora extra";
  }
}
```

**Me pueden explicar**

El procedimiento que estoy realizando es correcto o a la vez es mejor utilizar un `switch`

> No soy tan experto en programación, pero jamás he visto un procedimiento igual, me puede explicar si el procedimiento realizado es correcto, siempre he visto que al añadir más `if` en un `else` se hacia de esta manera: `elseif`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un switch para no escribir más de una vez la variable $operation a la cual haces referencia.

```
// switch
switch($operation){
  case "extra":
    //
    break;
  case "noextra":
    //
    break;
  default:
    //
    break;
}
```

O un else if

```
// else if
if ($operation == "extra") {
  //
} else if ($operation == "noextra") {
  //
} else {
  //
}
```

Usualmente se utiliza **else if()** para hacer referencia a otra comprobación de la misma variable. (En este caso $operation).
Se podría cambiar por un **if()** si hicieras una comprobación de una variable diferente.

```
if ($operation == "extra") {
}
if ($numero == 3) {
}
if ($palabra == "hola") {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`elseif` como su nombre lo sugiere, es una combinación de `if` y `else`.

Del mismo modo que `else` extiende una sentencia `if` para ejecutar una sentencia diferente en caso que la expresión `if` original se evalúe como `FALSE`.

Sin embargo, a diferencia de `else`; esa expresión alternativa sólo se ejecutará si la expresión condicional del `elseif` se evalúa como `TRUE`.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente código debe mostrar `a` es mayor que `b`,  `a` es igual que `b` o `a` es menor que `b`:

```
<?php 
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "a es mayor que b";
 } elseif ($a == $b) {
            echo "a es igual que b";
 } else {
    echo "a es menor que b";
 } 
?>
```

- Puede haber varios `elseif` dentro de la misma sentencia `if`. La primera expresión `elseif` (si hay alguna) que se evalúe como `TRUE` sería ejecutada.

En PHP también se puede escribir `else if` (en dos palabras) y el comportamiento sería idéntico al de `elseif` (en una sola palabra). El significado sintáctico es ligeramente diferente (si se está familiarizado con C, este es el mismo comportamiento) pero la conclusión es que ambos resultarían tener exactamente el mismo comportamiento.

La sentencia `elseif` es ejecutada solamente si la expresión `if` precedente y cualquiera de las expresiones `elseif` precedentes son evaluadas como `FALSE`, y la expresión `elseif` actual se evalúa como `TRUE`.

Sin embargo la sentencia `Switch` se define:

> La sentencia switch es similar a una serie de sentencias IF en la misma expresión. En muchas ocasiones, es posible que se quiera comparar la misma variable (o expresión) con muchos valores diferentes, y ejecutar una parte de código distinta dependiendo de a que valor es igual. Para esto es exactamente la expresión switch.

Por Ejemplo

```
<? php
switch ($i) {    
    case "manzana":         echo "i es una manzana";
        break;
    case "barra":        echo "i es una barra";
        break;
    case "pastel":        echo "i es un pastel";
        break;
} 
?>
```

Es importante entender cómo la sentencia `switch` es ejecutada con el fin de evitar errores. La sentencia `switch` ejecuta línea por línea (en realidad, sentencia por sentencia). Al principio, ningún código es ejecutado. Solo cuando se encuentra una sentencia `case` cuya expresión se evalúa a un valor que coincida con el valor de la expresión `switch`, PHP comienza a ejecutar la sentencias. PHP continúa ejecutando las sentencias hasta el final del bloque `switch`, o hasta la primera vez que vea una sentencia `break`.